# How do i specific names and print region containing it?

Tags: python

Python learner: Any help would really be appreciated.

Hi, I have a text file with different cluster having different name of sequence and size. I want to extract whole cluster if it has all the initials of all the four names (st104,pK,NE,TIG) does not matter if the initials are duplicates.

Search for **st104,pK,NE,TIG** initial of (st104H_20170,pKH911_25081,NE95031.1,TIG_004920) in the input file and print out as below.

**input.txt**

Cluster 1 
0   673aa -st104P_06575 
1   673aa -st104H_22488 
2   673aa -TIG_004920 
3   673aa -pKH911_09284 
4   673aa -pKP911_09288 
5   696aa -NE95031.1  
Cluster 2 
0   673aa -st104P_06575 
1   673aa -st104H_22488 
2   673aa -st104H_22500 
3   673aa -pKP911_09284 
4   673aa -pKP911_09288 
5   696aa -NE95031.1  
Cluster 3 
0   690aa -st104H_20170  
1   690aa -pKH911_25081 
2   687aa -NE95031.1 
3   685aa -TIG_004920 
Cluster 4 
0   685aa -st104H_27649 
1   690aa -st104P_11877  
2   685aa -pKP911_15300 
3   685aa -TIG_004920 \

**expected output**

Cluster 1 
0   673aa -st104P_06575 
1   673aa -st104H_22488 
2   673aa -TIG_004920 
3   673aa -pKH911_09284 
4   673aa -pKP911_09288 
5   696aa -NE95031.1  
Cluster 3 
0   690aa -st104H_20170  
1   690aa -pKH911_25081 
2   687aa -NE95031.1 
3   685aa -TIG_004920

Thank you so much. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Please describe more precisely what you want to do. Also, please tell us what you tried.

Comment: Hi, michico1234, I have a text file with different cluster having different name of sequence and size. I want to extract whole cluster if it has all the initials of all the four names (st104,pK,NE,TIG) does not matter if the initials are duplicates. Thank you

Comment: Please add your explanation directly to the question, so that others can know what you're asking for when they come here. It's also important to write how you tried to solve the problem - otherwise it looks like you want us to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to write a parser for your file format. I suggest the following (I didn't test this code, it may have bugs):

```py
with open(input_file) as fh:
    result = ""
    cluster_content = ""
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("Cluster"):
            if all(initial in cluster_content for initial in required_initials):
                result += cluster_content
            cluster_content = ""
        cluster_content += line
```